# Regular expression match anything including newlines

Tags: c#, regex, match, newline

I have string like:

```
/* Remove */
"REMOVE" = "Löschen \
";
```

And I have regular expression to match strings between  " " = " "

```
"(\S+)"\s*=\s*"(.*?[\w\r\n]).*?";
```

What I have to add to match if string have more newlines in it, eg:

```
/* Remove */
"REMOVE" = "Lös \
ch \
en \
";
```

Comment: This doesn't look like any known source code string. What if your string contents contain a `"` in the body? `"REMOVE"="th;is"con;tent"; ;"";`

Comment: then there is problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `(.*?)` and a dotall flag with which makes the dot match newline characters too :

```
(?s)"(\S+)"\s*=\s*"(.*?)"
```

See demo https://regex101.com/r/vM3tG6/2

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
"(\S+)"\s*=\s*"([^"]*)";
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zI6fO0/3)

`[^"]*` is negation pattern that will match any character (including newline) except a double quote.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
(.*)"\s*=\s*"((?:.|\n)*)
```

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/aW1bZ8/2)

Comment: but it doesn't match text after newline

Comment: @user3308470. Sorry for that. Now it does.